# How to add images to UserControl menu in Wpf

Tags: wpf, image, mvvm

```
enter code here<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EPOS.Desktop.View" 
     xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:EPOS.Desktop.ViewModel"
     xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:EPOS.Desktop.UserControls"
     xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core" xmlns:dxwui="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/windowsui" xmlns:dxn="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/navbar" x:Class="EPOS.Desktop.View.MainSaleUI"

    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainSaleUI"

    Width="1046" Height="500" Left="500" Top="500"
    Background="SkyBlue" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    >


<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:QeueOrdersViewViewModel}">
        <UserControls:QeueOrders />

    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TillViewModel}">
        <UserControls:TillUC/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SettingViewModel}">
        <UserControls:Settings/>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid Margin="0,67,65,0">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxMenu"                    
             Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Settings}"
             SelectedIndex="0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="10"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,10,5" BorderBrush="#FF7F9DB9" BorderThickness="1">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxMenu, Path=SelectedItem}" Margin="0,0,225,0"/>
</Border>

</Grid>
```

> Blockquote

How to add images to User-control menu in Wpf. These are dynamic menus. Is there way to add images to every text?

Comment: Do you want image in your ContextMenu or just for ListBoxMenu?

Comment: with context menu.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you exactly want... assuming that you want to display some image right after /before the text on your listbox you can add an image property in your "settings" class (Binding of your Listbox's Itemsource) and change your listbox's datatemplate content with something like this :

```
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="10"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding Image }" />
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Can you give me some more details ? do you have any message in the output window when you run your application ?

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand what you exactly want to achieve. You want to have some picture right after the text in your menu in first column ? or do you want to display a specific image on the right column when you select something on your left menu